# Is this character immortal?

Tags: dc, doom-patrol

The *Doom Patrol* TV show is about the eponymous team of misfits. The team is lead by the Chief (Niles Caulder), a genius doctor, and is composed of the powered people he repaired after an accident: Elasti-Woman, Negative Man, Robot Man, Crazy Jane,...

A common characteristic of the powered members of the members of the Doom Patrol is that they are seemingly immortal. For example, Elasti-Woman is the 60s actress Rita Farr that can stretch her body. She has problems to control her power but the positive outcome is that she doesn't seem to age. Robotman is a brain inside a robotic body so, spare some maintenance, he probably doesn't care about dying of old age. Negative Man is inhabited by the Negative Spirit that has been shown to heal him.

This becomes a plot point when

> we learn that the Chief orchestrated the accidents that turn them into freaks. His goal was precisely to find ways to prolong life and study immortality, in order to stay alive long enough to watch over his extremely powerful (and potentially dangerous) daughter.

The problem is that

> Chief is seen alive and adult before WWI. We don't know his age at that time but the events of the show take place in 2019 so he is well over 100. He is also portrayed in the scenes in both eras by Timothy Dalton, and didn't show any sign of aging.

Hence my question: **Is Chief also immortal?**

I haven't read the comics but the show seems to follow them quite closely. If there is no answer from the show, I would be happy to know about information from the comics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [the comics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_(comics)):

> Caulder developed an interest in creating better life at a young age. Proving at a young age to be both a brilliant inventor and engineer, Caulder received funding from a mysterious benefactor. Thanks to the funding, Caulder succeeded in creating a chemical capable of prolonging life. Ultimately, it was revealed that the benefactor was a man called General Immortus, who hired Caulder to create a chemical to replace the one that had been prolonging his life for centuries but was now failing.

That plot point has not yet shown up in the show, with [the reveal in Episode 10, "Hair Patrol,"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cbr.com/doom-patrol-dc-universe-miles-caulder-chief-origin/amp/) being that his prolonged youthfulness since a bit after 1914 is

> mystical, the gift of his neanderthal lover Slava, who performs a ritual to bring him back from his death, making him somewhat immortal.

Comment: Note that in the last episode, we learn that the series of experiments The Chief is doing at The Ant Farm in this area is grouped under the name "The Immortus Project".

Comment: I thought it was something related to the Prehistoric Woman (fountain of youth or something like that) but I missed that scene. I will have to rewatch the episode :D